# Which of the following lenses do fit on a Nikon D 3100

Tags: lens, dslr, autofocus, film

I've been given the following lenses from my neighbour; which ones will fit a Nikon D3100?

- Sigma 28-200 mm F F3,8 - 5,6
- Nikon Af 70-210mm F/4,0-5,6
- Nikon Af 28-85mm F/3,5-4.5
- Nikon 50 mm F 1.4
- Nikon Nikkor -Q-C- Auto 1: 2,8 F = 135 mm
- Zoom Nikkor C Auto 1: 4,5 f0 80 mm - 200 mm
- Zoom Nikkor 43-86 mm 1:3,5
- Nikkor -H-C Auto 1:3,5 f = 28 mm

A friend told me that not many of them will fit, but they would all fit a D300 or a D7000, since both of these bodies have an autofocus feature built-in. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nikon D3100 is able to use pretty much any F mount lens, but since in lacks focus motor, auto-focus is available only for AF-S lenses. Also you will need AF or AF-S lens for metering (older lenses are usable in manual mode).

D300 or D7000 use the same mount, so lens compatibility is almost the same. The only difference if that they have build-in focus motor and will be able to auto-focus with AF lenses and that metering is supported for AI and AI-s lenses. On other hand older pre-AI lenses will not mount on these cameras.

Comment: hello dear Sergey - many thanks for the answer. Great to hear that. If i **get you right** then it is a good idea to buy **a D 300 or D7000**. I will take this **into consideration**. Many many thanks again